# UIButton click event crash after adding the viewcontroller's view as a sub view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, addsubview

I want to add several `ViewController`'s views as sub views of my another `viewcontroller`. So I have done like this inside my parent `viewController`.

```
-(void)MakeDisplayArea
{
vwDisplayArea=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h-scrolTab.frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:vwDisplayArea];
}





-(void)ProfClick :(id)sender

{

    [self MakeDisplayArea];
    ProfileViewController *profviewcontroller=[[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    profviewcontroller.view.frame=vwDisplayArea.frame;
    [profviewcontroller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [vwDisplayArea addSubview:profviewcontroller.view];

}
```

Then inside the `profViewcontroller` `ViewDidLoad` methods I am generating a button and set the target like this.

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30)];
[btn setTitle:@"Button Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)btnClick :(id)sender
   {

      NSLog(@"button clicked-------");
   }
```

I can see the button is appearing on that `profViewcontroller` that I loaded as a sub view, but when I click the button the app is crashing. What is the correct way add that `viewcontroller` as a `subview` on my first `viewcontroller`. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Read the docs in `UIViewController` about implementing a container view controller. You need to add the child view controllers in addition to adding the subviews.

Comment: What error does the crash log give you?

Answer (score 0):

Like maddy said you need child view controllers to add working subviews.

Look here: [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

But working with them is not easy. Ask yourself if you really need to implement it. For the most cases you don't need it.